# ranges::subrange in MSVC on Compiler Explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, range-v3, compiler-explorer

The following code compiles and runs just fine [with GCC 8.3](https://godbolt.org/z/nvn9rr) and with [Clang 10.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/ffzzrh), whereas it fails miserably [on MicroSoft shiny compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Gzan7o).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> edits{1,1,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,1,3,3,2};
    auto xxx = ranges::subrange(edits.begin(), edits.end());
}
```

Is there some flag that I'm missing?

Comment: It works with `/std:c++latest`

Comment: ranges isn't a part of c++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified `/std:c++17` and [`ranges::subrange` is not present in C++ 17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange).  Ranges-v3 also requires C++ 20 because it uses Concepts.

Compiling instead with `/std:c++latest` succeeds.

The errors turn out to be coming from a Concepts emulation layer bundled in Ranges v3, which evidently does not work correctly on the latest Visual C++'s C++17 mode.  According to the documentation, it needed experimental compiler options even when it did work, so best to just turn on C++ 20 support when using Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: I might have misunderstood you answer. Obviously `std::ranges::whatever` comes with C++20, not C++17, but what I use in my example is the Range-v3 library, not C++20 ranges library, and that does work in C++17. Nonetheless your suggestion of using the `/std:c++latest` fix the issue. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You mean that `#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>` is being processed as it was `#include <ranges>`???

Comment: And why do the other two compilers just fine with `-std=c++17`?

Comment: @Enlico: Maybe the `concepts/concepts.hpp` header included in Ranges v3 isn't broken on those compilers?  Maybe those compilers enable too many featuers in C++17 mode?